# vim script throw E488: Trailing Characters

Tags: vim

I have this on my vimrc:

```
" close all buffer except active buffer
function! CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()
  let l:curr = bufnr('%')
  let l:last = bufnr('$')
  if l:curr > 1 | silent! execute '1,'.(l:curr-1).'bd' | endif
  if l:curr < l:last | silent! execute (l:curr+1).','.l:last.'bd' | endif
endfunction
command! BO :call CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()<CR>
```

This was used to close all buffer except the active one.
Everytime I invoke it using `:BO`, the function worked but I always got "E488: Trailing Characters" message.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`command` is not mapping so you don't need `<CR>`:

```
command! BO :call CloseAllBuffersButCurrent()
```

Comment: Right. Also you can drop the `:`, and by adding `-bar` you can include the command in a command sequence, e.g. `:BO | split newfile`